# Where can I get the time series mentioned in the exampkle "working-with-csp.ipynb"?

Tags: pysam

I would like to know where to get the time series (in csv) as mentioned in the Input [13] of the example working-with-csp.ipynb:

https://github.com/PyPSA/atlite/blob/master/examples/working-with-csp.ipynb

## Load reference time-series from file

df = pd.read_csv("../profiles_and_efficiencies_from_sam/ST-salt_time-series_spain.csv")

I can get the times series only but I need a table with the column "Estimated receiver thermal power TO HTF | (MWt)". I assume it's generated by PySAM but I wasn't able to create one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.